# Extract data from array in php

Tags: php, arrays

How can I extract data from this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => color / size 
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => blue / l 
                    [1] => blue / m 
                    [2] => red / l 
                    [3] => red / m 
                )
}
```

in this format?

```
color = blue,red
size = L,M
```

Comment: show how should look the whole final array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) will solve the purpose. Try this:

```
foreach ($array[0]['value'] as $k => $val) {
    $values  = explode(' / ', $val); // Break up string into array
    $color[] = $values[0]; // Store colors in this array
    $size[]  = $values[1];  // Store size in this array
}

echo 'Color = ' . implode(',', array_unique($color)); // First get unique values using array_unique, then convert this array to string using implode()
echo '<br/>';
echo 'Size = '. implode(',', array_unique($size)); // First get unique values using array_unique, then convert this array to string using implode()
```